# Fragment and LinearLayout in one XML file won't work - UPDATED

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two layouts that I am trying to integrate. One is just a map and the other is a textview stating my latitude & longitude coordinates. Both will work without the other but when I integrate the two of them into one layout xml file I am only getting the TEXTVIEW with no map! I have provided the xml file, manifest and class that calls the layout. Please help!

**activity_display_map xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Waiting for location..."
    android:id="@+id/lblLocationInfo"/>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0vFrUOhHMkbahT9zXqiz_DuNVWfPqlEyqcO8ftg" />

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**LocationActivity class**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;


  public class LocationActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";

LocationManager locationManager;
Geocoder geocoder;
TextView locationText;
MapView map;    
MapController mapController;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_map);  

    locationText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.lblLocationInfo);
    map = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        this.onLocationChanged(location);   
    }

 // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,   10, this);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());
    // Displays lat, long, altitude and bearing
    String text = String.format("Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t   %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(),   location.getBearing());
    this.locationText.setText(text);

    try {
        // This gets a list of addresses 
        List<Address> addresses =    geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10);
        for (Address address : addresses) {
            this.locationText.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0));
        }

        // Convert latitude and longitude into int that the GeoPoint    constructor can understand
        int latitude = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000);
        int longitude = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
        mapController.animateTo(point);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.travsafe"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.travsafe.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.travsafe.LoginSignupActivity" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.travsafe.Welcome" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.travsafe.Camera"
        android:label="@string/title_camera"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.travsafe.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.travsafe.MainActivity" />
    </activity>        

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.travsafe.LocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_map"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.travsafe.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.travsafe.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyCSWI9L4rkIDdM9HRdg_JHy3lVgykCBzyI"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: why do you have a `MapView` and a `MapFragment` in the same layout?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to
   android.view.ViewGroup`

Comment: I have a MapView to retrieve my longitude & latitude and a MapFragment to display my map!Is this wrong?

Comment: @StewyYes that is very wrong, if you are using MapFragment you dont need MapView and also google maps v1 is no longer supported. remove the MapView completely

Comment: So what do I do then with the code that is in MapView? Make it part of my fragment?? I tried this but it just crashes again!